# Java Swing how to drag and drop files from dir to dir

Tags: java, swing

I am looking for help with creating a gui. I want to create 2 frames, and be able to move files betwen them. Something like in total commander. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmQF7.jpg)

Where can I find tutorials? I dont even know how to look for them.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :)

Comment: Have you tried entering 'java swing tutorial' in to Google?

Answer (score 0):

At first make sure, that you know what you want to use. You typed in title Swing, and in tags you've set swt. 
It's not soo easy to create gui like that. At first start learning from basics, about frames, panels and object's that in swing. Then learn about events and soo on.
Here you have greate tutorial : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/swing/

Comment: I know those basics . The main problem is that I dont know how that kind of gui is called and what kind of tools should I use ;)

Comment: Swing has drag and drop functionality. Try this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/index.html